# Avoiding Duplicates in SharePoint List from Microsoft Accounts Using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, duplicate, if-condition

I've set up a flow in Power Automate to add the names, cities, and workplaces of my colleagues to a SharePoint list using their Microsoft accounts, and it's working well. However, I'm encountering a challenge: whenever a new team member joins, I want to add them to the list. As of now, when I rerun the Power Automate flow, it creates duplicates for everyone already in the list. I would like to know how to avoid these duplicates every time the flow is triggered.

I understand the concept of implementing a Condition to check each unique value (such as email addresses) against the input to avoid creating duplicate entries. However, I'm facing a challenge in applying this in practice.

Since I am retrieving all attributes of each user, these attributes always exist, making it unclear how to effectively use the Condition step to identify and prevent duplicates. As someone new to Power Automate, I'm finding it a bit complex to navigate.

I attempted to follow this approach, but unfortunately, it didn't work as expected. Could you please provide some more detailed guidance or examples on how to correctly set up this Condition step in the flow? Any step-by-step instructions or tips specifically tailored for beginners would be incredibly helpful.

[image]